# How to activate "Waze" from phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova

How to activate the Waze Application from a Hybrid application (such as Phonegap)?
Is it by the following command line?

```
<a href="waze://?q=Hawaii">waze application</a>
```

or by:

```
document.location.href = "waze://?q=Hawaii"
```

thanks in advance:

Kobi

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used them before but I think you should check out webintents.  The git for the pluggin is pretty active too, usually a good sign.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/WebIntent/